# React usePrevious does not seem to be having previous value

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect

In my React functional components, I am trying to use custom usePrevious to get/compare the previous value of my context object. However, it seems to be having the latest value always and not the previous value. Below is my code. Please let me know if I am doing something wrong here.

```
function MyHeaderComponent(props) {
    const [myPref, setMyPref] = React.useContext(MyContext);
    const prevPreferences = usePrevious(myPref.preferences);
    
    useEffect(() => {
        console.log("prevPreferences : " + prevPreferences);        // Prints current context object, instead of the previous one
        // I want to call myInfo only if prevPreferences is not the same as myPref.preferences (i.e. current)
    }, [myPref]);
        
    function usePrevious(value) {
        const ref = useRef();
        useEffect(() => {
            ref.current = value;
        });
        return ref.current;
    }    

    const myInfo = async () => {
        setMyPref(myPref);
    }

    return (
        <>
            <div>
                Some JSX
            </div>
        </>
    )
}


export default withRouter(withStyles()(MyHeaderComponent));


function MyPreferences(props) {
    const [myPref, setMyPref] = React.useContext(MyContext);
    
    // somewhere in code
    setMyPref(myPref);                
}
```

Comment: Why is that custom hook defined inside the component? You get a whole new hook every time, that's unlikely to help retain any history.

Comment: I tried to reproduce it. I couldn't https://codesandbox.io/s/boring-cray-z628s?file=/src/App.js. Please provide your Minimal reproducible sample.

Comment: @jonrsharpe - Even after creating as separate file/hook, I face the same issue...

Answer (score 0):

That implementation of `useLatest` (which should not be within the component, by the way) does not copy the value into the ref box, it just assigns a reference.

I'd wager `myPref.preferences` gets internally modified (instead of being reassigned a new object), which is why you always see the same value.

Comment: So there is no way to get the old value ?

Comment: Either make your `useLatest` hook copy the value (e.g. Lodash's `cloneDeep`) or ensure that you always assign a new value into it and don't modify it internally.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is you are using usePrevious hook inside another functional component. Could you try to create a file for the usePrevious hook.

usePreviousState.js

```
function usePrevious(value, initialValue) {
  const ref = useRef();
  useEffect(() => {
    ref.current = value;
  }, [value]);
  if (ref.current === undefined && initialValue !== undefined) {
    return initialValue;
  }
  return ref.current;
}
```

Comment: Thanks...tried that....same issue...